# GoodData: Metadata extraction failed: SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state

Tags: sqlite, gooddata

I am using CloudConnect to access an Sqlite db.
It's an example db, found here:
http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/55169#DownloadId=167067

I am getting the following error:

```
Metadata extraction failed: SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state
```

I successfully set up a connection, and am trying to "Metadata" > "New Metadata" > "Extract from database".
I can see all the tables, although some tables appear twice and three times.
I select a table, "validate" works and "view" returns the proper result. When I click "next", I get the above "inconsistent internal state" error.

Possibly relevant side note - if I run the following:

```
SELECT sqlite_version() AS 'SQLite Version'
```

I get:

```
3.6.20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this seems to be bug, I just created request to our developers to fix this.

Jiri Simon

GoodData  Technical support.
https://support.gooddata.com